# Java desktop application for access to Google+

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, social-networking, google-plus

I'd like to connect to Google Plus with a Java client for a desktop application. Does anyone any example about how to connect to Google+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a java starter project at http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/ which sounds like it will get you up and running very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

The Google + API:
https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Use HTTP to send your requests and JSON to parse the answers:
http://json.org/java/